# Website offline viewing/editing

Tags: ftp, web, local, offline, editing

I went into the back end FTP for my website and downloaded it all to my C drive. My question is now does it show up in a browser as a normal address just with a different beginning, ex. file:///c:/folder/www.websitename.com or what would I type in to access the pages? I need to do some heavy lifting on it and don't want to do it to the site while its live. The dev site redirects to the main site and I can't find anything in the htaccess file that reroutes it so I'm just gonna try it this way. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just open the main page on the browser via file explorer? And it all depends on how the links are, is it all static etc, which we don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

The path will be something like this:

```
file:///c:/folder/filename.html
```

You can open the file in your browser by:

1. Opening it from the File menu in your browser.
2. If you are editing it in a tool like Notepad++, there should be an option to Launch the page you're editing in a browser. (In Notepad++ it's under the "Run" menu)
3. Go to the file in Windows Explorer/Finder, right click the file, select "Open With", and pick the browser you want to see the page in.